# Are these Aliases Superfluous?

Tags: sql, refactoring, alias

I'm looking at some legacy SQL that looks like this (the names of the tables and schemas were changed to protect the whatever):

```
. . .FROM ABC.ENMITY ENMITY, ABC.ABCROLL ABCROLL, ABC.ABCSLACKER ABCSLACKER. . .
```

Are these aliases of value? Wouldn't the following work without them:

```
. . .WHERE ENMITY.STRIFE = :strife AND ABCROLL = :bun AND ABCSLACKER = :punk. . .
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are completely useless.

They have no effect at all, because they essentially alias the table name as itself. Removing them would have no effect.

They may have been put there by some code generation tool.

Comment: Yes, it seems you were right about, specifically: "Ver 2.0,QBE - Integra Visual Database Builder"